# An interactive graph of Math.SE tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, community

Some time I created
[A Graph Map of Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/a-graph-map-of-math-se), which met with a warm response from this community. Encouraged by this, I created a new visualization, this time *interactive* and *up-to-date* (as long as the SE API lives): **TagOverflow**. For Math.SE, it is: http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/?site=math&size=32. Code and description is [here](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#tagoverflow).

Besides looking at the graph, you can:

- get interesting information per tag,
- get some statistics (like average score for these tags).

I hope you enjoy it!

EDIT: I am waiting for your insights and ideas how to improve it. (It my be good to post these as "answers".)

[image]

Comment: Makes me wonder why we have a separate "matrices" tag

Comment: @user7530: There were *three* movies.

Comment: You must be mistaken... there was talk of making a second movie, but it never happened.

Comment: @user7530 There is an older discussion somewhat related to (linear-algebra) and (matrices) tags: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/should-questions-on-matrices-and-matrix-equations-be-also-tagged-as-linear

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Obligatory XKCD](http://xkcd.com/566/)

Comment: @anorton: I hold a firm belief that the sequels were good. Sure, not good in comparison to Ingmar Bergman or Sergio Leone, but they were good for Hollywood bullet-fest movies; and I did like the embedded fatalistic nihilism there.

Comment: I find the most informative view to be "median owner reputation."  It's quite clear that there are certain topics where a *ton* of new people ask questions, but only a few high-rep people do.

Comment: @anorton it doesn't seem to work on the 64-tag version?

Comment: @user7530 Worked fine for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/oFs9F.png

Comment: I get intermittent errors "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stared.github.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503." when switching to conditional subgraph, but can't reproduce reliably. By the way, you are using API v2.1 which works but 2.2 is the current version.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Always or only when you choose many tags or do many queries?

Comment: I got it with size=16 on my second conditional subgraph. The API request goes instead to the page "There are an unusual number of requests coming from this IP address", instead of returning JSON object with backoff parameter or such. It seems the issue is not the total number of requests, but their rapidity. Are you keeping track of `backoff` response?

Comment: This may be the 30 requests/second limit [mentioned here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle): "exactly what response an application gets (in terms of HTTP code, text, and so on) is undefined when subject to this ban; we consider > 30 request/sec per IP to be very abusive and thus cut the requests off very harshly."

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat It's browser-only, so I cannot keep any logs. I set some delays for calls, but I am getting errors from time to time. But waiting for a few minutes "heals" it (see readme of TagOberflow).

Comment: [This question of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788318/the-category-of-small-categories-a-zoo-of-functors) might interest you, @PiotrMigdal :)

Comment: Am I the only one who gets a bit woozy watching it settle into place? :-)

Comment: _way cool,_ heard about this in physics chat room, just tried for other site cs.se, worked like a charm, posted info in [cs.se]. really like uses of [data.se] & think there is much more possibility of datamining than has been explored. some basic description of the algorithm would be helpful. how vertices decided, what graphics pkg/ libraries you use if any, etc

Comment: +1. Supernal! Would you please consider replicating this for other SE sites? Alas, I'm too unversed in Comp Sci.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/ and in menu bar just choose the site you want to visualize.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal +1. Thank you! I ineptly overlooked that menu bar. May SE advertise your wonder on all the sites.

Comment: It counts proof-verification and solution-verification as two different tags.